# Handling errors when using combineLatest on several service calls

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5, ngrx-effects

With the following piece of code (taken from an @Effect() in ngrx/store)

```
.switchMap(({token, param1, param2}) => {
  return Observable.combineLatest(
    this.service.getData2(token, param1),
    this.service.getData2(token, param2),
    this.service.getData3(token),
  );
})
```

What would be the most succinct yet correct pattern to catch the errors?
Should the .catch follow every `getData*` call? We don't want `.catch()` at the end of the main `@Effect()` chain, do we?

The question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41755718/how-to-trap-errors-from-chained-rxjs-observables-when-using-combinelatest), yet a bit different in that I don't a `.subscribe()` call here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This totally depends on the desired behaviour. Lets asume you are fetching 3 animals which you will display. What do you want to happen when one fail?

- Do not display any animal. -> add a `catch` to the end
- Display the other animals. -> add `catch` to each data call.